Understanding a step in the proof of Lemma 5.7 of Milnor's Singular points of complex hypersurfaces
Let $f(z_1,\dots,z_m)$ be a complex polynomial which vanishes at the origin. Let $K=\{z\in \Bbb C^m:f(z)=0\}$, and let $S_\epsilon$ be the sphere of radius $\epsilon>0$ centered at the origin. Define $\phi:S_\epsilon-K\to S^1$ by $\phi(z)=f(z)/|f(z)|$. For $e^{i\theta}\in S^1$ let $F_\theta$ denote the fiber $\phi^{-1}(e^{i\theta})$, and $a_\theta:F_\theta\to \Bbb R$ the function $a_\theta(z)=\log |f(z)|$.
In Milnor's book Singular points of complex hypersurfaces, we have
Lemma 5.7. There exists a constant $\eta_\theta>0$ so that the critical points of $a_\theta$ all lie within the compact subset $|f(\mathbf{z})|\geq \eta_\theta$ of $F_\theta$.
Proof. If there were critical points $z$ of $a_\theta$ on $F_\theta$ arbitrarily close to zero, then these critical points would have a limit point $z_0$ on the compact set $S_\epsilon$. Using the curve selection lemma, there would exist a smooth path $p:(0,\epsilon')\to F_\theta$ consisting completely of critical points, with $p(t)\to z_0$ as $t\to 0$. $(\cdots)$
Here the curve selection lemma is:
Curve Selection Lemma. Let $V\subset \Bbb R^n$ be a real algebraic set, and let $U\subset \Bbb R^n$ be an open subset defined by finitely many polynomial inequalities: $U=\{x\in \Bbb R^n:g_1(x)>0,\dots,g_l(x)>0\}$. If $0$ is contained in the closure of $U\cap V$, then there exists a real analytic curve $p:[0,\epsilon)\to \Bbb R^n$ such that $p(0)=0$ and $p(t)\in U\cap V$ for $t>0$.
Question. How should we apply the curve selection lemma in the proof of Lemma 5.7? I cannot see how Milnor took $U$ and $V$ for the application of the curve selection lemma.
